# Game-based or nasty chatbot for Facebook Messenger or Skype

Tags: game-ai, intelligent-agent, chat-bots

Are there chatbots for Facebook Messenger or Skype available which are game-based, i.e. with which it is possible to play a short funny game? It should be possible to play the game for at least 10 minutes in sequence and it should be writing based and not based on clicking at boxes. That means the agent should be pretty clever, like Microsoft Zo bot, but instead of conducting random smalltalk a game should be played.

Second, are there bots for Facebook Messenger or Skype available which are nasty and unfriendly, i.e. which are offending?

Thank you a lot in advance. I'm thankful for any help.

Comment: my sense is no, (but, one of my goals is an ai that can not only play games but trash talk ;)